# Android, Navigation Drawer NullPointerException, No ActionBar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make a Navigation Bar by using the example provided from [android](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). 
I've downloaded the code and implemented it into my project. I don't know why it doesn't work, it's a sample.

Here my logcat and my jar.

```
01-30 13:26:51.958: D/AndroidRuntime(580): Shutting down VM
01-30 13:26:51.958: W/dalvikvm(580): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ch.antum.antumapp/ch.antum.antumapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at ch.antum.antumapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919) 
01-30 13:26:51.969: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

I have the right imports and package name. 
It is a `NullPointerException` but I can't find anything missing. Also the logcat doesn't really specify in which file or on which line an error occurred. I had no problem debugging my projects when I wrote java applications. But, with android I can't really use the logcat usefully, any tips?

PS: I'm not using the `ActionBar`, but the code does, so may this be a problem? I've simply deleted the parts which where commented as `ActionBar`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's line 93 of MainActivity class? Thanks. It's a NullPointerException issue.

Comment: oh thank you, I only saw these big numbers like 4000, 4250 etc, overlooked the 93. That's: if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    } the selectItem part. It's sample code and I don't really know what that line is doing, or what argument it needs that it works

Comment: That method is used when you click on an item of the menu so the system can allocate and open the related Fragment. 0 is a default value so when the user open the app it automatically shows the first fragment. You should put a breakpoint in that method and go line by line to see where is failing... are you sure mPlanetTitles is not null?